Syntax Error when creating a loop for feature class conversion
I am creating a loop to convert shapefiles in a folder to a geodatabase. For some reason I get a syntax error near the not statement. When I remove the if clause the script works no problem. I want to fix this so I can keep my data clean and for future steps I will be doing a batch projection and clip.
I commented out the previous tools since they worked.


Post your code as text and not as an image

Using Walk - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation is a more Pythonic way of listing data sets.

Replace
if fc not '82I_TWP.shp':
with
if fc != '82I_TWP.shp':
(or fc != '82I_TWP, Im not sure if ListFeatureClasses includes the file prefix or not).
And indentate the line after one level.
!= is the "Not equal" operator

oh right okay, I tried != but forgot to indent the line after. Thank you!

Nice! What should I do when someone answers my question?
